# Default.aspx not firing events

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, telerik

We have recently put up a new server with IIS7, where we now have published a .NET4 site.

Locally everything works fine, but on this server the Default.aspx is not working. No events are firing at all for this page. Every other page works as should.

We've tried deleting the Default.aspx and adding a new blank one with just a button event but same thing still applies.

We've spent quite some time troubleshooting this without any results. Same problem exists both with and without using a masterpage.

<sub>*Edited to add:*</sub>

After more research it was a module from Telerik that caused it. When disabling RadCompression everything work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

> Locally everything works fine

On your local IIS or Cassini?

Check for "AutoWireUpEvent" property in the page directive

Answer (score 0):

That's really weird. Maybe you can try: Find other machines to visit the site, to see if it's working. If you are using IE, go to Internet Options->General->Settings->Check for version of stored pages->Every visit to the page. And even delete all temp files then try.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**
When `RadCompression` is enabled and you are using .NET 4.0, event handlers might not be raised in a default document in IIS 7 or IIS 7.5 Integrated Mode.

**Solution**
This problem is caused by a breaking change in .NET 4.0 described here. To workaround it one can set `precondition="managedHandler"` for the `RadCompression` module. You may also need to remove the `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests` setting from your `web.config` if you have it (or set it to false).

Described here:
http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/radcompression.html

Comment: Missing your 'described here' link Syed.